# how to encode a video file to x265 10bit main10 profile in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, libx265

I'm currently trying to encode a video file with `ffmpeg -i input.mkv libx265 crf=28 -x265-params profile=main10 out.mkv` but i am getting the output file is in 8 bit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the input isn't already 10-bit, you have to first convert it, usually using `-pix_fmt`.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -x265-params profile=main10 out.mkv
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why little-endianness is used here? Will `yuv420p10be` produce a different result?

Comment: That happens to be the native endianness on my machine. Run `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx265` to see yours.